# Is the Sum of Coefficients of a Continued Fraction unique?

Tags: number-theory, summation, continued-fractions

Let $a$ be a rational number and
$$
a = a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\ddots}} \iff a = [a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_i]
$$
a corresponding continued fraction. Now, the coefficients of $a$, i.e $a_0,a_1,\ldots$ are not unique. Take for example
$$
2 = [2] \quad \text{or} \quad 2 = [1,1].
$$
But it appears to me, that the sum of the coefficients $a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_i$ is indeed unique. Is this true? How can it be proven?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181724/uniqueness-of-continued-fraction-representation-of-rational-numbers

Comment: Note, continued fractions are usually understood to have *positive* integer coefficients. If you don't make that assumption, then, for example, $1=[1]=[3,-1,2]$ with $1\not=3-1+2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra But that post says the representation is unique and a finite continued fraction has two representations.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Barry Cipra okay, so if we omit negative integers for the coefficients this should be resolved?

Comment: @SirSocket https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Finite_continued_fractions

Comment: @saulspatz, you get uniqueness when you require the last coefficient, $a_n$ to be greater than $1$ (when $n\gt0$).

Comment: @BarryCipra That's what I missed.  Thanks.

Comment: To summarize the answer implicit in the comments: for finite continued fractions with all coefficients integers and all but first positive this follows from essential uniqueness (e.g per Wikipedia). If a coefficient after the first can be negative this isnt true, e.g. Barry's example. If the continued fraction isn't finite and has integer coefficients the sum trivially diverges or oscillates. I suppose the only remaining question is whether two representations with rational coefficients whose sums exist must have equal sums (I'd look for counterexamples with common constants like $\pi$)

Answer (score 0):

I have understood this question to mean that, for example, there is only one way of expressing $\frac{1}{2}$ as a fraction but there are two continued fraction expressions of $\frac{1}{2}$, namely, [0; 2] and [0; 1, 1]. The question is (I think) why this is the case.  My answer is that it is not actually the case.  For example: $\frac{1}{2}$ can be written as a continued fraction $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}$ and generally $\frac{p}{q}$ can be written as $\frac{p}{(q-1)+\frac{1}{1}}$ .  This is an unusual and generally unnecessary way of writing a continued fraction but it can be useful when considering, for example, the ordering of continued fractions and reversal of continued fractions.